# How to create multiple varibles with multiple values

Tags: c++, struct

I'm making a game where the user has to stop people from hacking into their company's database/security.

Currently, I have a variable `int threats;` that I can assign a value to. This doesn't work because I need to have multiple threats that have their own type, like DDos or Malware, and they also need names, like $DDoSThreat%.

This has been killing me for weeks, all help would be appreciated.

Comment: A variable has one value at a time, but you can subdivide that value, bit masking for example, or have an array of values.

Comment: Maybe you need a container like std::vector<T> or std::map<T1, T2>

Comment: Has it really been taking you WEEKS just to define a few variables? Sounds like you need to get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Answer (score 1):

You could've used `std::vector<>` for storing multiple struct types using a single variable.

Look at the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Malware {
    std::string name;
    bool danger;
};

void getMalwareDetails(Malware); // parameter: struct

int main(void) {
    std::vector<Malware> malware; // HERE'S WHAT I'M TALKING ABOUT
    Malware mTemp; // for temporary
    char ask;

    do {
        std::cout << "Malware name and is that danger (1/0)? : ";
        std::cin >> mTemp.name >> mTemp.danger;

        malware.push_back(mTemp); // adds the info to struct

        std::cout << "Add more? (Y/n): ";
        std::cin >> ask;

    } while (ask == 'Y' || ask == 'y');

    for (int i = 0; i < malware.size(); i++)
        getMalwareDetails(malware[i]); // get the struct info

    return 0;
}

void getMalwareDetails(Malware m) {
    std::cout << "Name: " << m.name << " Danger?: " << m.danger << std::endl;
}
```

Create a `struct`, use `std::vector<STRUCT_NAME>`, add the struct values to the vector variable on each iteration then finally display them. Similarly, you may use one more struct for `DDos`.

> **Sample Output**

```
Malware name and is that danger? : $DDoSThreat% 1 // --- INPUT
Add more? (Y/n): y
Malware name and is that danger? : Trojan 1
Add more? (Y/n): y
Malware name and is that danger? : Google 0
Add more? (Y/n): n
Name: $DDoSThreat% Danger?: 1 // --- OUTPUT
Name: Trojan Danger?: 1
Name: Google Danger?: 0
```